# How can I get a closed trade data from Kucoin Futures account using ccxt?

Tags: python, ccxt, kucoin

I have a Python script to get past trades, gives me the order info but I'm looking to get data for a closed position, like closed price, leverage entry etc., and as a bonus if available PnL.

Here is the Python script to get my trades:

```
import ccxt
import json
import sys

key = 'key'
secret = 'secret'
password = 'password'
symbol = 'BTC/USDT:USDT'

ku = ccxt.kucoinfutures({
    'adjustForTimeDifference': True,
    'apiKey': key,
    'secret': secret,
    'password': password,
    'enableRateLimit': True,
})

# Call the API to get all trades
all_trades = ku.fetch_my_trades(symbol)

#show all trades but doesn't include the closed order data
print(all_trades)
```

I've gone through the ccxt docs but don't see anything about the data about the trades closed price or other relevant data.

[https://docs.ccxt.com/](https://docs.ccxt.com/#/)